# What are the Hebrew names for the 3 kabbalistic garments of thoughts, feelings and actions?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

I'm watching a video on Tanya and the rabbi said those 3 words in Hebrew, but I can't figure out what those words actually are on Google so I can add them to my notes.

---

What are the words in Hebrew? I know what they are in English. Kind of like chochma, binah and daat, there are English words, but people refer to those concepts using the Hebrew.

Comment: What video was it?

Comment: I found it. Machshavah-Thought, Dibbur-Speech and Maaseh-Action

Comment: If you have an answer you should post it as such below.